# How to send a dict of namedtuples or just a namedTuple to a client (socket)?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

Simply put, I have a dictionary (`dictData[name]=namedTuple`) of namedTuples (records) on a server.

Objective: I want to send the entire thing (`dictData`) or a single instance (`dictData[key]`) to the client via a SOCKET connection so it can be printed (shown on screen).

To send a single record I have tried to do the following:

```
response = dictData["John"]
print (response) #ensure it is the correct record
s.send(response)
```

However this generates the following error:

```
"TypeError: 'record' does not support the buffer interface"
```

I have tried to encode it and convert it but nothing I do seems to work. I am even open to converting it to a STRING and sending the string but I can't seem to find out how to convert a namedTuple to a string either.

And then, no clue where to start to send the entire dictionary to the client so they can print the entire set?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sockets can only send and receive bytes, so you need to serialise your named tuples and dictionary to something else.

You could use JSON to produce a string representation of your tuples and dictionary, for example. The [`json` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) produces a (unicode) string when encoding, you'll need to encode that to UTF-8 (or similar) to produce bytes:

```
import json

# sending one tuple
response = json.dumps(dictData["John"])
s.send(response.encode('utf8'))

# sending all of the dictionary
response = json.dumps(dictData)
s.send(response.encode('utf8'))
```

This will *not* preserve the named tuple attribute names; the values are sent over as a JSON array instead (so an ordered list).

Another option is to use the [`pickle` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html); this would require the listener on the other side to also be coded in Python *and* to have the same `record` named tuple type importable from the exact same location, however.

When Pickle loads the data, the name of the full qualifying name of the `namedtuple` type is included, and you must be able to import that type on both ends of the socket. If you have a line in a module at the global level:

```
record = namedtuple('record', 'field1 field2 field3')
```

then `from yourmodule import record` is possible, but *the exact same import* should work on the other side too.

`pickle.dumps()` produces a `bytes` object which can be written to the socket without encoding.

Comment: Actually, a better encoding in this case would be [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

Comment: @whereswalden: that depends on what is listening on the other side.

Comment: @Martijn you mentioned ordered, can this be sorted by name as well?

Comment: Pickle or JSON - not sure I know which is best ... the other side is just a dumb client (socket) that will print the data to a user.

Comment: @JSchwartz: for your named tuples?

Comment: @JSchwartz: If the other side is also coded in Python and you can have the `record` object definition importable (pickle will use the same full name with module to import the same class again) then you could use pickle here and get the same object types.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well the requirement is for "sorted users", specifically the client is prompted "select operation" and if they choose 7 (print report) or 6 (print record for "John") I send the request to the server who needs to respond with the requested data. Client is only used to SEE data on the server

Comment: The other side is PYTHON 3.x also (I am writing both together)

Comment: In that case, pickle would work fine. Just unpickle it before handling it on the other side.

Comment: @JSchwartz: Then you mean to sort the *keys* of the dictionary. Do so on the receiving end when printing; dictionaries themselves are unordered.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but the receiving end (using pickle) will have a dictionary anyways no? how do I sort it?

Comment: @JSchwartz: Yes, you'd have a dictionary if you use JSON or pickle. You'd use `for key in sorted(yourdict): value = yourdict[key]` to iterate over the sorted keys.

Comment: Odd ... I don't think Pickle plays nicely with a DICT[key]=namedTuples because of the nesting

Comment: @JSchwartz: Pickle can handle nesting just fine. If you are getting an error then something else is up.

Comment: Hate putting code in comments but ... this is what I have. 'UserData = namedtuple("name", "age address phone")' defined globally then within my SocketServer Handler I do this 'response = self.server.dictData' and then 'pickledData = pickle.dumps(response, -1)' and this generates _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.name'>: attribute lookup name on __main__ failed

Comment: @MartijnPieters when I creating my dict I do 'user = UserData(age, address, phone)' to create an instance of my namedTuple and I add it to my dictionary 'self.dictData[name] = user'

Comment: @JSchwartz: right, that's because your `namedtuple()` is called *`name`*, not `UserData`. Use `namedtuple('UserData', 'age address phone')`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters LOL - dead on :) Ok ... last question on this ... on the CLIENT side, how do I rebuild my dictionary or namedTuple (depending on if I sent a single record or the enter dictionary)?

Comment: @JSchwartz: `object = pickle.loads(data_from_socket)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and it will somehow know that object is either a dict[name,namedTuple) or a namedTuple with the proper fields? (you can see I am a C++ developer lol)

Comment: @JSchwartz: yes, the pickle protocol includes type information. Which is *why* the `namedtuple` object must be importable on the other side too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you take a look at my new posting? I am getting EOFError's sometimes and I am worried it is because I am not getting the full pickle data in one shot ... if so ... not sure what to do from here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726495/pickle-eoferror-ran-out-of-input-when-recv-from-a-socket